# Let $f$ and $g$ be simple functions that agree almost everywhere, that is $m(\{x \mid f(x)\ne g(x) \})=0$. Show that $\int_X f = \int_x g$.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f$ and $g$ be simple functions that agree almost everywhere, that is $m(\{x \mid f(x)\ne g(x) \})=0$. Show that $\int_X f = \int_x g$.

My idea was to construct $h=f-g$ and show that $\int_X h = 0$ since by linearity I would have that 0= $\int_X h = \int_X (f-g) = \int_X f - \int_X g$ which would imply the result.

Since $f$ and $g$ are simple $h$ is simple also and something of the form $h= \sum_{n=1}^N c_n 1_{E_n} - \sum_{k=1}^K a_k 1_{F_k}$. Now I have a bit of trouble showing that $$\int_Xh = \sum_{n=1}^N c_n m(E_n) - \sum_{k=1}^K a_k m(F_k) = 0.$$ Any hints on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$h=f-g$ is itself a  simple function. Write $h= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}a_n {E_n}$ where $E_n$'s are disjoint measurable sets and $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$.  Then $h=0$ a.e. implies that each $E_n$ has measure $0$. So $\int h d\mu=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}a_n m({E_n})=0$, so $\int f d\mu=\int gd\mu$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f-g$ is itself a simple function, and so, is mensurable. So how
$m(\lbrace f \neq g \rbrace ) =0,$, we can write

$$ \int_X f - \int_X g = \int_X (f-g)= \int_{\lbrace f=g \rbrace} (f-g) + \int_{ \lbrace f \neq g \rbrace } (f-g) = 0+0=0.$$

Therefore,

$$ \int_X f = \int_X g .$$